# Unable to Customize Spree User Registration Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I am trying to add few new text fields to my registration form(First name, last name, Contact no).

I have browsed through complete source code of Spree 2.1 but could not find any relevant section. But on searching text "Password Confirmation" I found following in the

```
en.yml(located at config/locales/en.yml file)

spree/user:
        email: Email
        password: Password
        password_confirmation: Password Confirmation
```

As Spree Uses devise for sign in/up mechanism hence explored the view section by running

```
`rails generate  devise:views`
```

Hence tried to modify relevant file `new.html.erb (app/views/devise/registartions/new.html.erb).`

But none seems Working. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put custom view to

```
app/views/spree/user_registrations/new.html.erb
```

And restart server after.

Copy from views from here: https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise/tree/master/app/views/spree

Comment: It worked. Just copied to the contents to my projects-> view->complete spree folder. 
Thanks NARKOZ !

Comment: There is no such page found. How to customize registration view?

Comment: They moved the views in `lib` directory. https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise/blob/master/lib/views/frontend/spree/user_registrations/new.html.erb